# Regex to remove all parentheses except most external ones

Tags: regex

I have been trying and reading many similar SO answers with no luck.
I need to remove parentheses in the text inside parentheses keeping the text. Ideally with 1 regex... or maybe 2?

My text is:

> Alpha (Bravo( Charlie))

I want to achieve:

> Alpha (Bravo Charlie)

The best I got so far is:

```
\\(|\\)
```

but it gets:

> Alpha Bravo Charlie

Comment: will the parentesys always be balanced?

Comment: yes, and only one pair of nested one

Comment: In essence, you want to get rid of the inner most parenthesis. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: What should be the output if the input is `Alpha (Bravo( Charlie) Colin (Gamma(Hey)))`? Also, what should be the output if the input is `(ALPHA)`?

Comment: Which programming language do you use here?

Comment: ECL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hpcc-ecl)

Comment: May you have a string like `Alpha (Bravo( Charlie) (Bar))`? If yes what would be expected?

Comment: No, we should not have it...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\(.*?)\((.*?)\)
```

[image]

With this replacement string:

```
$1$2
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zpDf9o/1)**

---

Update: as per [ııı](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579078/%c4%b1%c4%b1%c4%b1) comment, since I don't know your full sample text I provide this regex in case you have this scenario

```
(\([^)]*)\((.*?)\)
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zpDf9o/2)**

Comment: This is also incorrect (test with the input `Alpha (Bravo Charlie) Alpha (Bravo( Charlie))`)

Comment: Now it doesn't work for this string `Alpha (Bravo Charlie) Alpha (Bravo( Charlie) Hey (Charlie))` It only replaces first parenthesis but not second. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zpDf9o/3)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi that doesn't look like op text `Alpha (Bravo( Charlie))`, according to his comment he won't have your case.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza: Exactly this is what I had been saying too that OP doesn't have the case raised by other spectators/commenters, but they were only bashing my answer and not other answers, due to which I had to comment on another answers that even other answers are failing while trying to cover cases not mentioned by OP. Actually regex isn't the right tool for solving the kind of problem OP posted.

Answer (score 1):

From your post and comments, it seems you want to remove only the inner most parenthesis, for which you can use following regex,

```
\(([^()]*)\)
```

And replace with `$1` or `\1` depending upon your language.

In this regex `\(` matches a starting parenthesis and `\)` matches a closing parenthesis and `([^()]*)` ensures the captured text doesn't contain either `(` or `)` which ensures it is the innermost parenthesis and places the captured text in group1, and whole match is replaced by what got captured in group1 text, thus getting rid of the inner most parenthesis and retaining the text inside as it is.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sWea95/1/)**

Comment: @Downvoter: Is something wrong in my answer? Please let me know.

Comment: @OscarFoley: Thanks for upvote. I am wondering why other answer got upvotes and mine got downvote. Where as mine answer seems simpler and works for cases where there are more than two levels of nesting.

Comment: @OscarFoley Care that this actually turns a desired string `Alpha (Bravo Charlie)` into `Alpha Bravo Charlie` if it exists in the input string.

Comment: Yes, it would be a problem

Comment: @revo: You're making a case that wasn't specified by OP. Also, if you read OP's above comments that were posted before my answer he clearly says "yes, and only one pair of nested one" even after which I specifically asked him whether he wants to remove the inner most parenthesis to which he confirmed yes. By definition of inner most parenthesis, if there is only one then that will be removed and OP hasn't mentioned about it anywhere. My answer was better from both perspective, performance as well as case coverage. Before downvoting an answer, you should heed to the answer on multiple aspects.

Comment: It's a missing point. OP didn't state it and you didn't ask it. By the question they don't want to change parentheses in `Alpha (Bravo Charlie)` but yours change it and I just warned them. BTW I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: Well, you're right about your case, but I went for that answer as OP wrote, he had only one pair of nested one, so I side lined it. Anyway, let me cover that case as well.

Comment: Your pattern would also match without the outer closing parenthesis https://regex101.com/r/AhTayh/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: If you see someone asked to OP in comments, "will the parenthesis always be balanced?" to which OP replied "yes, and only one pair of nested one", so my answer works perfectly fine not just for that but also, if there are more than one nested pairs of parenthesis. Creating a case which is already denied by OP will not be of much use. And if you really ask me, regex is not the right tool for solving this kind of problem. You try to cover one case and some other case gets missed. Notice, my answer covers maximal normal cases and is most performant among all the posted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `\(|\)` uses an alternation then will match either an opening or closing parenthesis.

If according to the comments there is only 1 pair of nested parenthesis, you could match:

```
(\([^()]*)\(([^()]*\)[^()]*)\)
```

- `(` Start capturing group
- `\(` Match opening parenthesis

  - `[^()]*` Match 0+ times not `(` or `)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\(` Match
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `\([^()]*\)` match from `(` till `)`
  - `[^()]*` Match 0+ times not `(` or `)`
- `)` close capturing group
- `\)` Match closing parenthesis

And replace with the first and the second capturing group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ISVRUc/1)

Comment: The solution is unfortunately incorrect (your own demo shows the output `Alpha Bravo( Charlie)`)

Comment: How is this correct? Shouldn't this `Alpha (Bravo( Charlie) (Bar))` be changed to this `Alpha (Bravo Charlie Bar)` i.e. remove the inner most both parenthesis?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi The example data shows only 1 set of parenthesis. According to the question in the comments if they are balanced, the answer is `yes, and only one pair of nested one`. According to another question `May you have a string like Alpha (Bravo( Charlie) (Bar))` the answer is `No, we should not have it`. So my answer is based on that information.